# Ignore default value of class when instantiating

Tags: typescript, class, oop, parameters, constructor

Below you see a simple TypeScript class and two instantiations of it. Normally, when you're creating an instance of the Car-class, you should be able to pass your own values for the class-properties as parameter, like with 'carName'. But you see in the constructor I've already set a default value to 'maxSpeed'. Now my two questions:

1. At the instance of "myCar", how can I tell it to pass the predefined maxSpeed of "265" which is predefined in the constructor? Doing it like "this.maxSpeed" gives me an error, but I don't get a way around it.
2. At the instance of "yourCar", how can I omit/ignore the predefined standard value for maxSpeed of 265, and pass my own value, like 311 i.e. as shown in the example below?

I'm very new to programming and OOP and have not much knowledge at the moment about it.

```
class Car {
  carName:string;
  maxSpeed:number;

  constructor(carName:string, maxSpeed:number) 
    {
      this.carName = carName;
      this.maxSpeed = 265;
    }
}

//How can I pass the predefined constructor-value? What is my mistake?
var myCar = new Car('Tesla X', this.maxSpeed);

//This should print "265":
console.log(myCar.maxSpeed);

//How can I break the rule of the predefined constructor-value and get this 311 printed in the console? It still prints me the 265.
var yourCar = new Car('Tesla X', 311);

//This should print "311":
console.log(yourCar.maxSpeed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Car {
  constructor(public carName: string, public maxSpeed: number = 265) {}
}
```

This is all you need:

- parameters may define default values, allowing to omit them when calling the constructor/function (maxSpeed does that, so you can just do `const myCar = new Car('Tesla X');`)
- if a constructor parameter is also a property of the class, you can just declare it with a visibility modifier before the constructor argument. So the above is the compact version of

```
class Car {
  carName: string;
  maxSpeed: number;

  constructor(carName: string, maxSpeed: number = 265) {
    this.carName = carName;
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  }
}
```

I would renamed `carName` to `name`. Of course it's a car name, since it's a property of the class Car. So the `car`prefix is redundant.

Also, don't, ever use `var`. Use `const` (if the variable shouldn't be reassigned) or `let`.

Comment: Thank you, both your solutions work totally fine! And thanks for the naming tips!

Comment: Can you tell me why could there be a case, where a constructor parameter is NOT a property of the class? (I'm new to OOP and programming in general). I would really like to just always write the class like you did in the first three lines of your answer and don't do it the way I did in my question at the top. But why can't it always be written in that compact way you did?

Comment: You can always use the compact way. Just don't put public, protected or private before a constructor argument, and it will be just that: a constructor argument, and not a property? Why would you want that? When you just need an argument to do something with it in the constructor. Trivial example: `constructor(name: string) { this.name = (name || 'anonymous').toUpperCase(); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say in the Class/constructor after the maxSpeed variable I add a third variable. Then the solution by leaving maxSpeed empty wouldn't work anymore. Would then the legit/right way be, to put all variables with a default value AFTER all the variables without a default value? Or is this work-around below legit? By using 'undefined' it still logs maxSpeed = 265 as it should.

```
`class Car {
  constructor(
    public carName: string, 
    public maxSpeed: number = 265,
    public someThing: string
    ) {}
}

const myCar = new Car('Tesla X', undefined, 'test');

console.log(myCar);`
```

Comment: @jb-nizet Do you think this way of using undefined is legit? Or should I put all variables that have a default value always at the end of the class/constructor?